# There is why to use Blob to set <img> content, without using FileReader or URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, html, image, blob

I know that I can use `FileReader` or `URL.createObjectURL` to parse `Blob` into a string and set the `image.src` with it.

But I want to know if I can set Image content directly with a `Blob`?.

Comment: what's the problem? why do u need to do that? I mean, put blob directly as `src`.

Comment: ‘URL.createObjectUrl’ not supported in IE and you have to clear that objectUrl later to avoid memory leak. And ‘FileReader’ is an async function tha need some time and jade some effect on the performance (in case you want to display many frames per second). So I wander if I can assign it to ‘Image’ object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a blobURL that you do create using `URL.createObejctURL(blob);`.

In comments you state that you have concerns about browser support and memory usage (you even talk about memory leak...).

#### Browser support

Only a few versions of Chrome did support the FileReader object while not supporting URL.createObjectURL (IIRC that was around v14). Internet Explorer added support in IE10, just like they did for the Blob object and FileReader.

#### Memory usage

A blobURL is just a pointer to data that is either already in memory, or only on disk. A pointer has like no weight in memory.
A dataURL on the other hand is a string representation of binary data. It weights around 34% more than the data it represents (because binary needs to be mapped to more safe-characters).

Now, to paint the image that is at the other end of the URIs,

- for a blobURI, the browser would directly parse it and generate the bitmap from it => memory usage ~2.5x the size of the image (just like if it was downloaded from a server).
- for a dataURI, the browser would first parse the string (but can't get rid of it) to gain access to the binary format (1.34x + 1x) then it will parse it and generate the bitmap from it (+2.5x => 4.84x).

Not only this, but if you are going to assign this dataURI in multiple places, then it's 1.34x more data every time you simply copy the string, and given the how hard it is to cache a dataURI, you end up using a lot of memory to represent the same binary data...

**Memory leaks?**
No. There is no memory leaks. It is simply that when a Blob gets referenced by a blobURL, then this Blob can't be collected by the GarbageCollector, for as long as the blobURL has not been revoked. But given that blobURLs life-time is tied to the Document that did create it, it will die anyway at next refresh.
Also, if you are dealing with data that come from the user's disk, then the blobURL is really just a pointer and no data is stored in memory.

---

There are really only a few use cases for the `readAsDataURL` method of the FileReader, and unless you are sure you must use it, then just use a blobURL.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly set `image.src` with a `Blob`. The `image.src` needs you to provide an url which is based on an http link, base64 data or virtual blob url address. `Blob` is a binary object and doesn't belong to any kind of above options. As you say `Blob` needs `URL.createObjectURL` to convert it to a virtual blob url address that can be recognized by `image.src`.